# laravel5.8 Request failed with status code 500

Tags: php, laravel, axios, laravel-5.8

Im trying to create search bar with axios laravel for need per title and description, but i have this error

```
Error: "Request failed with status code 500"
    createError http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:633
    settle http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:796
    handleLoad http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:166
```

and i dont understand where is the problem,

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>Mokoch</title>



    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}" >
                    <img src="{{ asset('svg/logo.png') }}" width="25%"  >
                    <span class="ml-">Mokoch</span>
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                  <!--   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="{{ route('posts.index') }}" class="nav-link">Voir les offres</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul> -->

                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('post.search') }}" onsubmit="search(event)" id="searchForm">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="form-control" id="words">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Rechercher</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->nom }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

                                    <a href="{{ route('posts.create') }}" class="dropdown-item">Mettre une annonce</a>

                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
        <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    @yield('extra-js')

</body>
</html>
```

welcome.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">

    @foreach ($posts as $post)
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

       <a href="{{ route('posts.show', ['post' => $post->id]) }}"> <img src="{{ asset('storage') . '/' . $post->image }}" class="w-100"></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ $post->title }}</h5>
        <small>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($post->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}</small>
        <p class="card-text">{{ $post->descriptionpost }}</p>
        <p class="card-text">{{ $post->price }}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Voir</a>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach

</div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
    @section('extra-js')
    <script>
        function search(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault()
            const words = document.querySelector('#words').value
            const url = document.querySelector('#searchForm').getAttribute('action')
            axios.post(`${url}`, {
                words : words,
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
        }
    </script>
    @endsection
```

PostController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\Poststore;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $posts = DB::table('posts')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(1000);

        return view('welcome',['posts'=> $posts]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'title' => ['required', 'string'],
            'image' => ['required', 'image'],
            'price' => ['required', 'integer'],
            'descriptionpost' => ['required', 'string']
        ]);

        $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');

        $image = Image::make(public_path("/storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);
        $image->save();


        auth()->user()->posts()->create([
            'title' => $data['title'],
            'descriptionpost' => $data['descriptionpost'],
            'price' => $data['price'],
            'image' => $imagePath
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('profile.show', ['user' => auth()->user() ]);
    }

    public function show(Post $post)
    {
        return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
    }

    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $words = $request->words;
        $posts = DB::table('posts')->where('title', 'LIKE', '%$words%')->orWhere('descriptionpost', 'LIKE', '%$words%')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'posts' => $post]);
    }
}
```

Someone know where is the problem? what i can doing for leave this error because search bar not work :/ ?

Comment: in .env file APP_DEBUG=true then refresh the page. See the error.

Comment: Make sure you have writtable folder permission to /bootstrap & /storage

Comment: its not permission, @AliÖzen  i dont understand error in console its this :Error: "Request failed with status code 500"
    createError http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:633
    settle http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:796
    handleLoad http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:166

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use csrf token in your axios header:**
sample code below:

```
const words = document.querySelector('#words').value
const url = document.querySelector('#searchForm').getAttribute('action')
const data = JSON.stringify({
            words: words
        })
axios.post(`${url}`, data, {
                headers: { 
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token.content 
                }
            }).then(
                response => console.log(response.data)
            ).catch(
                error => console.log(error)
            )
```

Comment: okok im ok but where is header axios in laravel ? because i learn and i dont very good know

Comment: axios is made with js.when it hit a api url it need to contain some additional information which it contains in its header. as your project is in laravel thats what define csrf in header is important.otherwise it will not work

Comment: i dont get your question? can you make it cleat.